# ASP NET Core application with SQL Server (local) database published on Azure platform

Tags: database, azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET Core MVC application and published it directly via VS 2022 to Azure. It includes EF and Identity.

What is the best approach to also connect the database with data?

I have connected the database, but that didn't work as expected. All the data is missing

Comment: Could you please provide your approach and the error what you got?

Comment: I didnt really get a error. After publishing from Visual Studio, i created a SQL database in Azure. However, i dont think thats the right way to do it because i already have a local database. I need that schema and data to also be in Azure and establish some kind of connection with the database.

Comment: Then publish your database to azure and connect it to your application.

Comment: Can you please tell me how

Comment: You can refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app) that shows how to deploy an ASP.NET Core app to Azure App Service and connect to an Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your local database to Azure and connect with Web application.
I deploy My local database which is having SQL server authentication by following below procedure:
I selected the database and right click on it I go to below option:

[image]

Clicked on Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database.
Connected to the Azure database server By clicking on connect option.
Image for reference:

[image]

It connected successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

Summary of operation:

[image]

I click on finish. The operation started and completed successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

My database is deployed to azure SQL database successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

In this way we can deploy Local database to Azure SQL database.
Connecting to application:
Create web application go to publish page of that

1. From the  **View**  menu, select  **SQL Server  Object Explorer**.
2. At the top of  **SQL Server Object Explorer**, click the  **Add SQL Server**  button.

In connect dialog box expand your azure node and connect to the database with username and password

[image]

Add client IP

[image]

database connected successfully.

[image]

In this way you can connect with azure SQL database.